# In C, how can I copy part of an array of strings for use as an argv in execve?

Tags: c, arrays, string, shell

My code is really messy right now, so I think it would be easier to convey what I'm trying to do by just describing it.

I'm working on a shell for homework that needs to be able to redirect output to a file, just like the default shell. We were provided a preexisting shell and asked to modify it. The shell already sets up an argv for execve, but in order to implement redirection I need to remove the last two entries from the argv the program built (> and the file name), and after testing that by just freeing up the last two entries I think it's probably better to just make a copy, minus those two entries, as this program handles freeing up the argv and if I try to do that at some point before the predesignated time to do so I run into problems when I try to run another command.

My point is I'm having a hard time copying part of an array of strings that's going to serve as an argv. I've seen a couple of solutions posted, but they're all in C++, and I'm asked to do this in C.

Alternatively, I suppose it would also be sufficient if I could properly empty part of an argv. Here's the code I tried:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(my_argv[i] == NULL)
    {
        break;
    }
    if(strcmp(my_argv[i], ">") == 0)
    {
        if(my_argv[i+1] != NULL)
        {
            strncpy(fileName, my_argv[i+1], strlen(my_argv[i+1]));
            strncat(fileName, "\0", 1);
            //bzero(my_argv[i+1], strlen(my_argv[i+1])+1);
            //my_argv[i+1] = NULL;
            //free(my_argv[i+1]);
        } else {
            printf("no file name given\n");
            return;
        }
        //bzero(my_argv[i], strlen(my_argv[i])+1);
        //my_argv[i] = NULL;
        //free(my_argv[i]);
        redirectOutput(cmd, fileName);
        return;
    }
}
```

The commented sections are where I copied in code from the function that empties my_argv to attempt to free up the contents of argv where the > and file name are. It still runs without those lines, but then I kick the can down the road with having to deal with the extra entries in my redirectOutput() function, which is an absolute train wreck. The free_argv() function looks like this:

```
void free_argv()
{
    int index;
    for(index=0;my_argv[index]!=NULL;index++) {
        bzero(my_argv[index], strlen(my_argv[index])+1);
        my_argv[index] = NULL;
        free(my_argv[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `strncpy(fileName, my_argv[i+1], strlen(my_argv[i+1]));` is a concern.  I'd expect something like `strncpy(fileName, my_argv[i+1], sizeof fileName); fileName[sizeof fileName - 1] = 0;`  `strncat(fileName, "\0", 1);` does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to much more work than you need to do.  You can safely do whatever you want to the pre-prepared `argv`, as long as you do it *after* the `fork()`, in the child (before the `execve()`, of course).  No such modifications will affect the parent, and you don't need to worry about any cleanup because the exec replaces the old process image with the new one.

Example:

```
/* these are already provided: */
char *filename =    /* ... */;
char **child_argv = /* ... */;
char **child_env  = /* ... */;

pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == 0) {
    /* the child */
    char **arg;

    for (arg = child_argv; *arg && strcmp(*arg, ">"); arg += 1) { /* empty */ }
    *arg = NULL; /* terminate the arg list at the ">", if present */

    /* no need to clean up anything before execve() */

    execve(filename, child_argv, child_env);
    exit(1);  /* execve() failed */
} else if (pid < 0) {
    /* handle error */
}

/* the parent continues ... */
```

Comment: Or if you're not `fork()`ing, then all the more reason not to worry.  Just make your changes directly to the prepared argv, and go.